# Why is U-Boot CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE preferred over CONFIG_OF_EMBED for boards in mainline

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot, device-tree

While working with U-Boot v2023.07, I noticed that when building the bootloader with the device tree blob embedded in the binary, the build process warns about preferring a separate DTB over an embedded one for mainline boards.

```
===================== WARNING ======================
CONFIG_OF_EMBED is enabled. This option should only
be used for debugging purposes. Please use
CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE for boards in mainline.
See doc/develop/devicetree/control.rst for more info.
====================================================
```

Can anyone explain the rationale behind this warning message?

The only explanation that comes to mind is that, due to the use of CONFIG_OF_EMBED, where the DTB is integrated into the binary, supporting multiple DTBs would likely require a complete rebuild of the entire U-Boot. In contrast, CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE appears to simply append the DTB at the end of the ELF file, potentially allowing for the replacement of the DTB without altering the original U-Boot ELF.

Comment: "*Can anyone explain the rationale behind this warning message?*" -- It's clearly stated in the reference document. "*Devicetree Control in U-Boot*" "*aims to make it possible for a single U-Boot binary to support multiple boards.*" You can't "*support multiple boards*" with a single dtb embedded in the binary. The Linux kernel (esp for ARM) adopted the use of Device Tree for the same reason.